# Exception stack trace is unreadable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting strange `stacktrace` when a `selenium exception` occurs:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'Some Text')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.103)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55f4eaa7f2c3 <unknown>
#1 0x55f4ea88883a <unknown>
#2 0x55f4ea8c1985 <unknown>
#3 0x55f4ea8c1b61 <unknown>
#4 0x55f4ea8f9d14 <unknown>
#5 0x55f4ea8dff6d <unknown>
#6 0x55f4ea8f7a50 <unknown>
#7 0x55f4ea8dfd63 <unknown>
#8 0x55f4ea8b47e3 <unknown>
#9 0x55f4ea8b5a21 <unknown>
#10 0x55f4eaacd18e <unknown>
#11 0x55f4eaad0622 <unknown>
#12 0x55f4eaab3aae <unknown>
#13 0x55f4eaad12a3 <unknown>
#14 0x55f4eaaa7ecf <unknown>
#15 0x55f4eaaf1588 <unknown>
#16 0x55f4eaaf1706 <unknown>
#17 0x55f4eab0b8b2 <unknown>
#18 0x7fb61f82b609 <unknown>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I am also interested in this. Could find any info about it online. In selenium 3 I was usually getting an empty list in stacktrace, and this came in selenium 4.

Comment: I was wrong in my previous comment. This is not related to selenium 4 exception. I had it when i was debugging on a remote machine, so maybe something related to network.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is clear:

> > NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'Some Text')]"}

It means Selenium failed to locate a web element matching the passed locator.
This can be caused by many causes, for example:

1. You passed a wrong text content `'Some Text'`
2. You are missing a delay i.e trying to locate an element while the page is still not completely rendered.
3. That element is inside an `iframe` or `shadow root`.
4. You opened another tab but did not switch the `driver` to the new tab.
5. The element is out of the visible page view port and that page do not load elements out of the visible view port before the page is been scrolled
   etc.

To give you more precise answer we need to see your code including the URL to the page you are working on.

Comment: Hi, I am asking about the `Stacktrace` which shows hexadecimal values. The exception message is clear, but I don't understand why `Stacktrace` shows such values

Comment: Well... You should ask your question more clear.... As about that Stacktrace I really don't know